# How to work with scripts in multiple folders?

Tags: python

I'm working on a translation *(don't know if this is the correct term)* of a code from MatLab to Python.
While I can take advantage of the differences between the two languages it has been asked me to keep the file/folder structure the same, but right now I'm having some problems with the import of functions.

Every file is contained in one folder, that contains a file `main.py` and a sub folder `programs`.
In `programs` I have a file called `do_stuff.py` and another folder `Data`.
In `Data` I have one last file called `DeviceData.py`.

The files are something like this:

`DeviceData.py`:

```
def FuncDeviceData():
    x=5
    return x
```

`do_stuff.py`:

```
def FuncDo_Stuff():
    y=DeviceData()+1
    print(y)
```

`main.py`:

```
FuncDo_Stuff()
   # TBN: code is oversimplified for clarity.
```

In the MatLab version there was a file used to add to the path all the subfolders but I honestly don't know how to do the same in python, or to do it "the python way".
I have tried the usual `from file import func` but I cannot find a proper solution.

P.S. I don't usually work with python, I'm kinda doing this for fun and it could be useful for the overall project.

Comment: you just want the subfolders right?

Comment: thx for the edit, yeah I just need to have access to all the subfolders and to the functions contained in all of their files

Answer (score 2):

Make a new python file `__init__.py` and keep it to `programs` folder. Then you can able to import functions from others python file to `main.py` .

Here is the folder structure:

```
── main_poject_folder
    ├── main.py
    └── programs
        ├── DeviceData.py
        ├── DoStaff.py
        └── __init__.py
```